# Why am I getting an unavailable declaration using framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm making a swift .framework, but I'm running into what I believe is a build problem. So I've simplified everything to isolate my troubles. I've attached a screenshot of my **newframework.framework** project (top) and my example usage of the framework (bottom). The problem I'm having is that `Whatever` class is unavailable when I include **newframework.framework**. I can confirm that **Whatever.swift** is indeed included in target>>buildphases>>compile Sources

What could cause this not to work?

[image]

**EDIT - Adding App Build phases screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I just replicated your exact situation here, and it worked first time for me. Could you show me the contents of your Build Phases for your app? It should have the framework inside its Link Binary with Libraries phase. Also, it looks like (from the tiny icons) you're building the framework for "Generic iOS Device" and building your app for the simulator. Is that correct? Have you tried matching devices? Minor addendum: building frameworks with Swift isn't a great idea right now because of the lack of ABI stability.

Comment: The mismatch of devices was indeed my problem. I guess I'm not entirely clear why that's an issue since one would presumably be able to use a framework on multiple devices but at least I know where to begin looking.

Comment: I've added a formal answer with the correct solution. If you have the time, please mark it as correct for others to benefit too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem, as we figured out in comments, was that you were building your framework for "Generic iOS Device" and building your app for the simulator. Xcode can't make the app build without matching architectures, so you need to choose one over the other or produce a framework that includes every architecture.

(This was posted to help people who come here from the future find the answer quickly. Hello, future people!)